# Strange behavior of ListView with WrapGrid in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app with a `ListView` nad `WrapGrid` as its ItemsPanel to display items in two columns

```
<ListView x:Name="ListV" ItemClick="ListV_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="160" ItemHeight="280" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Red" Margin="12" Width="100" Height="100"></Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The cache mode of the page is set to `NavigationCacheMode.Required`.

I scoll in the list, tap an item and navigate to another screen. When I navigate back to the page with the `ListView`, the `ListView` remebers the scoll position (`NavigationCacheMode.Required`) but gets "broken", when I tap on items, they just jump strangely.

Here is a complete simple solution to reproduce the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/listview.zip.

Here is a video showing the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/listview.wmv

Anyone else experienced this? Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround I've found is to wrap the `ListView` in a `ScrollViewer`. Here's a style for vertical scroll viewer:

```
<Style x:Key="VerticalScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
</Style>
```

And then you wrap the `ListView` like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}">
    <ListView ...>
        ...
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This way the `ListView`'s internal `ScrollViewer` is not used, and this seems to solve your problem. Now, there might be some issues with some features of the `ListView` that depend on the internal `ScrollViewer` to be used (e.g. incremental loading). You'll test it and you'll see if what you need works.

Comment: thanks, that works. any idea what is causing the strange jumping?

Comment: @IgorKulman I have no idea. It is indeed a very strange behavior.