# Strange behavior of FlipView with NavigationCacheMode

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have appeared very strange behavior of FlipView if I set NavigationMode to Enabled/Required and when I navigate to another page and then I go back, content of FlipView is jumping/disappering...

I appeared this [task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174696/strange-behavior-of-listview-with-wrapgrid-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml) where is described the same problem with ListView but that solution does not work for FlipView.

And I guess this [task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410973/making-flipview-with-navigationcachemode-stay-at-the-selectedindex) is the same but without some more specific description or sample.

Sample: http://1drv.ms/1H583zX

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock
                        Text="very long text"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Navigate" />

                    <TextBlock
                        Text="very long text"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```